# Difficulty spanning a row to full height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a columnar layout that works fairly well for my needs, but I am experiencing an issue with the height of one column. I have prepared a jsBin that demonstrates the problem;

http://jsbin.com/mawuliyulo/1/edit?html,output

Basically, when you scroll down - eventually you start seeing white on the left side. Is there any way to force this to stretch all the way down indefinitely?

This is not using a flex-box layout. It is simply achieved using `:before`, and `:after` pseudo-selectors.

Comment: I saw that question before, it doesn't solve the issue though as it assumes you are using flexbox, which I am not.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the flexbox question.

Comment: It's not a flexbox question. The top-rated answer uses Flexbox. Other answers don't.

Comment: I see. I will take a look at the non-accepted answers. But it was solved already down below - it was a simple fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to your main-container class

Comment: Thank you! That did indeed solve it! I will mark this as accepted in 9 minutes when it lets me. I didn't even think to try relative, I was trying to do everything with `clear`.